# Google Sheets script went rogue - adds 500 empty rows at bottom? (No running execution to terminate)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a weird issue at the moment with the following script I was testing:

```
function moveLeaversToBottom(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rowToMove = sheet.getRange("A2:2");
  var destination = 5;

  sheet.moveRows(rowToMove, destination);
}
```

After one of the runs, the code executed successfully and then my sheet started acting weird. Every few seconds (approx. 5 seconds) 500 empty rows are being automatically added to the end of the sheet. I don't know how to stop this, the logic in the code is not being executed anymore and I see no running execution that I can just terminate.

Do you know why this could be happening? Could it be because of the range I passed to .getRange?

```
var rowToMove = sheet.getRange("A2:2");
```

How do I stop this behavior?

Comment: Which cell are you referring to with your range?

Comment: Supposedly the whole second row. Doesn't that work in scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1);
```

Comment: Ok I guess? Why would I do that though, is it going to help me? :D

Comment: You can answer that question for yourself by looking at the values in your script debugger.